# Iterate over list

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, iteration

```
Q6
4;99
3;4;8;9;14;18
2;3;8;12;18
2;3;11;18
2;3;8;18
2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11;12;15;16;17;18
2;3;4;8;9;10;11;13;18
1;3;4;5;6;7;13;16;17
2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11;12;14;15;18
3;11;18
2;3;5;8;9;11;12;13;15;16;17;18
2;5;11;18
1;2;3;4;5;8;9;11;17;18
3;7;8;11;13;14
2;3;8;18
2;13
2;3;5;8;9;11;12;13;18
2;3;4;9;11;12;18
2;3;5;9;11;18
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11;14;15;16;17;18
2;3;8;11;13;18

import pandas as pd 
df_1 = pd.read_csv('amazon_final 29082018.csv') 
list_6 = list(df_1["Q6"]) 
list_6 = list(map(str, list_6)) 
list_7 = list(zip(list_6)) 
tem_list = [] 
for x in list_6: 
    if ('3' in x[0]): 
        tem_list.append('Fire') 
    else: 
        tem_list.append(None) 
df_1.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)
```

I have many such columns in data.
I want to extract value '3' from this, the code which i wrote is give giving me 3 value along with 13,23,33 so on. I only want count of rows having value 3.

Comment: show your code. Also, show desired output

Comment: my code:

import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.read_csv('amazon_final 29082018.csv')
list_6 = list(df_1["Q6"])
list_6 = list(map(str, list_6))

list_7 = list(zip(list_6))
tem_list = []
for x in list_6:
        if  ('3' in x[0]):
            tem_list.append('Fire')
        else:
            tem_list.append(None)
df_1.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)

Comment: please format this into your Q

Comment: In output column category in data should labels as 'fire' for the rows having no '3'

Comment: I think you mean "having '3'" not "having no '3'", at least that's what your code does. You need to break up the rows and convert each value to an integer. At the moment you are looking for the presence of the string "3" which is why the strings "13" and "23" pass the test.

Comment: yes i guess...will u help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break up the rows and convert each value to an integer. At the moment you are looking for the presence of the string "3" which is why strings like "2;13" pass the test. Try something like this:

```
list_6 = ["4;99", "3;4;8;9;14;18", "2;3;8;12;18", "2;3;11;18", "2;3;8;18", 
    "2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11;12;15;16;17;18", "2;3;4;8;9;10;11;13;18", 
    "1;3;4;5;6;7;13;16;17", "2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11;12;14;15;18", "3;11;18", 
    "2;3;5;8;9;11;12;13;15;16;17;18", "2;5;11;18", "1;2;3;4;5;8;9;11;17;18", 
    "3;7;8;11;13;14", "2;3;8;18", "2;13", "2;3;5;8;9;11;12;13;18", 
    "2;3;4;9;11;12;18", "2;3;5;9;11;18", 
    "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11;14;15;16;17;18", "2;3;8;11;13;18"]
temp_list = [] 
for x in list_6: 
    numbers = [int(num_string) for num_string in x.split(';')]
    if (3 in numbers): 
        temp_list.append('Fire') 
    else: 
        temp_list.append('None') 
print(temp_list)
```

Comment: yeah I am trying this

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solves things for you

Comment: If I have 2 such lists and and i want to extract value '3' from 1st list and '2' from 2nd list then how would be the code?

Comment: tem_list = []
for x in list_7:
    if ('1'in x[0]) & ('4'in x[1]) & ('4'in x[2] or'1'in x[3]):
        tem_list.append('Engage')
    else:
        tem_list.append(None)

Comment: You'll need to post another question with that in. Be careful to include the two lists in the question and include your code in the question so that people know you have tried first and can see where you are stuck. It is also worth marking solutions as answers. You haven't bothered on your first two questions which will put people off helping you.

Comment: Reached my question limit..:(   Could you help me here

Comment: That code you posted above, e.g. `if ('1'in x[0])` seems to still be looking for a string in another string. You will need to do the same trick we did here and split each list up and then convert the strings to numbers. Try it.